# Какой тип данных выбрать для переменной в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Я понимаю, что я туплю, но... Какой тип данных объявить для числа типа 4,46 в Delphi?

Answer (score 2):

`real`, `double`, `currency`. Смотря, что это за переменная, и что с ней будет происходить.

Answer (score 1):

В случае, если переменная не применяется для вычислений, связанных с денежными операциями, где погрешность критична, то имеет смысл выбрать `Real` или `Double`.

Отмечу также, что, если уж вы выбираете какой-либо определенный тип для операций с плавающей точкой, то используйте его везде в проекте - т.е если `Real`, то `Real`, если `Double`, то **везде** `Double` (ну разве что за редкими исключениями)

*Подробнее про вычисления с типом `Currency` можно прочитать [здесь.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/364x0z75(v=vs.90).aspx) Это, правда, описание аналогичного типа в C#, однако смысл и `problem domain` остаются теми же самыми.*

Comment: Позволю себе не согласиться. Типы разные нужны, типы разные важны. Не зная особенностей проекта, нельзя утверждать, что все должно быть только `double` или только `real`. Просто для каждой задачи нужно выбирать наиболее подходящий тип и понимать, почему он выбран.

Comment: @Nofate Это, возможно, дело вкуса, но я - за общность и один глобальный вещественный тип *(одинарной или двойной точности).* Оправданные случаи, когда какой-либо фрагмент кода использует тип `double` для повышения точности, но при этом оставшийся код использует `real`/`float` можно пересчитать по пальцам. *А вот проводить постоянные implicit кастования типов просто из-за того, что где-то человек решил написать `double`, а где-то `real` - это нонсенс.*

Comment: @Nofate Во многих игровых движках используется подход типа `#define USE_DOUBLE_PRECISION`, когда все вещественные типы автоматически становятся `double` или `float`, что тоже очень удобно. Точно так же, например, работают и флаги компилятора типа `/FP:fast` и `/FP:precise` в компиляторе `cl` (`Visual Studio`).

Comment: Я склонен думать, что в общем случае нужно использовать double и не парить свой мозг. Выигрыша от float, думаю, не получите. Если же необходимо экономить память - наш выбор - float. Еще момент - почему-то использование DX в с++ приводит к сваливанию всей вещественной арифметики в SP. <a href=http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmiller/archive/2004/06/01/145596.aspx>пример</a>